# Intent filter for dynamic links is not working as expected

Tags: android, deep-linking, intentfilter

I have following intent filter set up for detecting links to open in our app.

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="share.example.tv"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="example.tv"
                    android:pathPrefix="/u"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

I want my app to open below 2 links

1. https://share.example.tv/tv34gh
2. https://example.tv/u/some-user-name

But my app is showing up for these links as well

https://example.tv/anything/literally-anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I separate both of the links in different intent-filters for same activity like below

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="share.example.tv"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="example.tv"
                    android:pathPrefix="/u"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

This works but I don't know why.

Comment: Add this in question

Comment: @PankajKumar What do you mean

Comment: you added this as the answer to your question, so people will think you got an answer... So what I am saying is, add this section into question, not an answer.

Comment: This is the answer for my own question.
I struggled with this problem a lot and found solution today, that is why sharing my knowledge with potential people who might face it in future. @PankajKumar